# MongoClient Native FindAndModify "Need update or remove" Error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

My node.js client looks like this:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect(mongoendpoint, function(err, db) {
        if(err) throw err;
        var collection = db.collection('test-collection');

        var ws = new WebSocket(websocket_Endpoint);
        ws.on('open', function() {
                log.info('Connected.');
        });

        ws.on('message', function(data, flags) {

                wsevent = JSON.parse(data);

                var args = {
                        'query': {
                                id: '1.2.3.4'
                        },
                        'update': {
                                $set: {
                                        lastseen: "201405231344"
                                },
                                $addToSet: {
                                        record: "event123"
                                }
                        },
                        'new': true,
                        'upsert': true
                };

                collection.findAndModify(args, function(err, doc){
                        log.info(err);
                });
        });
});
```

When I run this, I get the **following error**:

```
info:  name=MongoError, ok=0, errmsg=need remove or update
```

I can't figure out why.  I can run the exact same `args` json above using RoboMongo and the query works just fine.

**Robomongo Query**

`db['test-collection'].findAndModify({"query":{"id":"1.2.3.4"},"update":{"$setOnInsert":{"lastseen":"201405231344"},"$addToSet":{"record":"event123"}},"new":true,"upsert":true});`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Your `args` section is wrong, it should be an array and does not need key values for "query" and "update". And the "options" value also needs to be an object (sub-document):

```
           var args = [
                    { id: '1.2.3.4' },
                    {
                            $set: {
                                    lastseen: "201405231344"
                            },
                            $addToSet: {
                                    record: "event123"
                            }
                    },
                    {
                        'new': true,
                        'upsert': true
                    }
            ];
```

Or specifically in the call:

```
collection.findAndModify(
    { id: '1.2.3.4' },
    { 
        $set: { lastseen: "201405231344" },
        $addToSet: { record: "event123" }
    }, 
    {
        'new': true,
        'upsert': false
    },
    function(err, doc){
```

Examples are also included on the [manual page](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#findandmodify).